# Screen Options not working for custom page templates

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a new Wordpress page template, but noticed something odd with the Admin's Screen Options functionality.

To start off with, I simply copied page.php to newpage.php and added the template name "New Template".  Without making any further changes to newpage.php and uploading it to my theme directory, I changed my page template to "New Template" in the Admin backend.  After doing this, I noticed that the screen options drop down tab no longer works (It is visible, but nothing happens when you click on it).  Switching the page template back to "Default Template" enables the screen options drop down.

Am I missing something else that needs to be done in order to enable screen options for the "New Template"?

Comment: have you added this as a comment in your template? `Template Name: New Template`.

Comment: Yes, I have and I can see "New Template" in the drop down list of templates.  The "New Template" is exactly the same as the "Default Template" (page.php), but the screen options don't work with the New Template while they work with the Default Template... why is that?

Comment: page for which you want to set the template is that page is assign to Blog page or Home page?

Comment: It is a regular page.  I just figured out that it might have to do with the theme that I'm using because if I use a different theme it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As WordPress Documentations says if you want to add a custom template for page `post_type` then you have to write this in your template file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: New Template
 */
```

---

Reference: [Creating Custom Page Templates for Global Use](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use)